# Websphere 8.5.5 log file does not show diacritics properly

Tags: logging, log4j

I have cxf based webservice with basic logging of all requests and responses.

Websphere settings is set to default (UTF-8 I guess, by forcing UTF-8 in JVM arguments casues no difference).

In logs file created by log4j there are ?????áíé instead of ěščřáíé. Request are sent through soapUI with UTF-8 set up. Such requests are saved in DB correctly, so I quess it is problem of logging - writing to the log file.

Have anyone ever experienced this kind of problem in WAS?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not seem to be a problem with WebSphere as your data is stored correctly in the database
It seems its is more a problem with log4j (did you specified log4j.appender.rollingFile.encoding=UTF-8 ?) or the editor/viewer you use to view the log file that does not support UTF-8 or convert the file to another codepage

Comment: You were right. log4j.appender.rollingFile.encoding=UTF-8 did the think. Thanx a lot!